# What is meaning of logical comparison of ethereum address | solidity

Tags: solidity, remix

I am reading [this smart contract](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v2-core/816075049f811f1b061bca81d5d040b96f4c07eb/contracts/UniswapV2Factory.sol). In that smart contract, they are comparing two addresses.

```
(address token0, address token1) = tokenA < tokenB ? (tokenA, tokenB) : (tokenB, tokenA);
```

What is the meaning of comparing two address. On what basis it will return true of false.

Comment: It has the exact same semantics as comparing integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line of code ensures that the passed tokens are sorted deterministically (e.g. token with lower address first), so that the pair address can be retrieved in a single lookup:

```
(address token0, address token1) = tokenA < tokenB ? (tokenA, tokenB) : (tokenB, tokenA);
    require(token0 != address(0), 'UniswapV2: ZERO_ADDRESS');
    require(getPair[token0][token1] == address(0), 'UniswapV2: PAIR_EXISTS'); // single check is sufficient
```

Hence the comment in the last line:

> single check is sufficient